# Attempt to print an array prints nothing

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I am trying to create an program that prints an array. I want the output of this program to be:

```
10000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

This is not what happens. Instead, it just prints nothing. There are no compiling errors. I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int a [5] [5] = {0};
    a [1] [1] = 1;
    int xcount = 0;
    int ycount = 0;
    while(xcount < 6);
    {
        cout << a [xcount] [ycount];
        xcount = xcount + 1;
        if(xcount = 6)
        {
            ycount = ycount + 1;
            xcount = xcount + 1;
            if(ycount = 6)
            {
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please indent your code. It is easier to read.

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: I don't remember if `{0}` will initialize the entire array or only the first element. You should check this using a debugger.

Comment: @Keith: it should initialize it to 0.

Comment: see xcount = 6 and ycount = 6

Comment: @ItzWarty Please don’t correct the code in an edit to the question – write an answer instead.

Comment: @Konrad: tmk I only added indentation. If I did otherwise, sorry about that.

Comment: The semicolon on the `while` line has been going in and out and the original poster hasn't edited the code once...

Comment: @nhgrif: ah, I see what you mean, my bad. I got a message that someone else had edited at the same time as me and assumed it was a merge error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you are trying to output the array by columns. Your code contains many bugs including the semicolon in the end of the while statement. The correct program could look the following way

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5; 
    int a[N][N] = { 1 };

    int xcount = 0;
    int ycount = 0;

    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << a[xcount][ycount];

        if ( ++xcount == N )
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            xcount = 0;

            if ( ++ycount == N )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (xcount=6)  // This sets xcount to 6
```

change that to:

```
if (xcount==6) // this compares xcount with 6
```

*Edit now that the ; is back in the question:*

Having `while(xcount < 6);` will loop infinately since nothing is changing xcount - remove the `;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon:

```
while (xcount<6);
```

Aside that, algorithm is wrong. Replace second

```
xcount=xcount+1;
```

by

```
xcount=0;
```

P.S. for loop would be better here. It would be much cleaner since you know range of loops:

```
for (int ycount=0; ycount<6; ++ycount)
{
    for (int xcount=0; xcount<6; ++xcount)
        cout << a[xcount][ycount];
    cout << endl;
}
```

Note there are no line deliminters in original solution.

P.P.S. use == in comparisons.

Comment: Then where would xcount change? You need to change it to move from left to right

Comment: There are TWO xcount increments, first is correct, second is not.

Comment: The while loop is wrong as well, but it will exit by             if(ycount = 6) { exit(0); }  (assuming there are two equal signs)

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I though he/she meant the first xcount=xcount+1

Comment: It still does not work. It prints 00000 and then a few negative numbers that are extremely long :/ Maybe there was something wrong with initializqtion

Comment: Append new code as well. There were too many errors in original.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a for loop instead of while 
Try this:

```
for(int xcount=0; xcount<5; xcount++) 
{
      for(int ycount=0; ycount<5; ycount++)
      {
              cout<< a[xcount][ycount];
       }
      cout<<endl;
 }
 a[0][0] = 1;
```